# How to modify more than two parallel threads in a UML sequence diagram

Tags: multithreading, uml, sequence, diagram, sequence-diagram

I need to create a sequence diagram with three parallel threads. I have gone through a couple of video tutorials and forums about UML sequence diagrams. However, none of them seem to answer my question. All of the examples are about exactly two parallel threads. Is it allowed to have more than two of them and if not, could you give me any suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: The parallel threads are represented with combined fragment (see my answer in the the suggested question above).  If you need more parallel threads,  just add some horizontal lines to add another slicle/thread to the box of the combined fragment.

Comment: So if I need three parallel threads I can add a second horizontal line to slice the box in three?

Comment: that's it, exactly!

Comment: I assumed it is possible but I was not 100% sure it is correct. Thank you for the help, much appreciated!

Comment: You're welcome :-)  If it helped,  you can upvote the answer in the linked question.